# Add custom method to useFormContext react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-hook-form

I have a complex form and I want to implement a hardSubmit method like this.

It works good,
The problem is I don´t know how add this method as valid whit TS

```
const Form=()=>{
  const hardSubmit = () => {
    console.log('hard submit');
    setFormStatus(FORM_LABELS.loading);
    handleSubmit((props: any) => {
      console.log('submit');
      onSubmit(props);
    })();
  };

Return(    
      <FormProvider {...methods} hardSubmit={hardSubmit}> //<--- TS don´t allow me add "add hardSubmit"
       <form
         onSubmit={handleSubmit((data: any) => onSubmit(data))
       >
         // ... nested compoonents
       </form>
     </FormProvider>
)}
```

Source : https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/

Comment: Create your own `FormProvider` component which extends the default `FormProvider` props and the custom `hardSubmit` you want to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment; you could create your own `FormProvider` component which extends the default `FormProviderProps` and the custom hardSubmit you want to add.

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { FormProvider, FormProviderProps } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props extends FormProviderProps<any, any> {
  hardSubmit: () => void;
}

export const MyFormProvider: FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  hardSubmit,
  ...formProps
}) => {
  return (
    <FormProvider {...formProps}>
      {children}
      <button onClick={hardSubmit}>hard submit</button>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};
```

You could use this like

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";
import { MyFormProvider } from "./MyFormProvider";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();

  const hardSubmit = () => {
    console.log("hard submit");
  };

  return (
    <MyFormProvider {...methods} hardSubmit={hardSubmit}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(console.log, console.log)}>
        <input placeholder="test" {...methods.register("name")} />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </MyFormProvider>
  );
}
```

Have a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-phoebe-ldo0ed?file=/src/App.tsx:0-684) for a working example